# Not able to update record using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I wrote one trigger that is working to create brother record from one object to another object.

actually i am able to insert record and it will inserted in another object as a brother record but after that i am not able to update that inserted record and it's effect does not affecting or updating it's brother record. (Sync scenario)

Help me out from this mistake...

Here is my trigger :

```
trigger SyncDealToOppData on Deal__c (after insert, before update) {

    List<Opportunity> newOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

    Deal__c dl = Trigger.New[0];

    if(Trigger.isInsert && checkRecursive.checkOneTime()){
        for (Deal__c deal: Trigger.New) {

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

            opp.Accountid = deal.Account__c;
            opp.Amount = deal.Stair_Total__c;
            opp.CloseDate = deal.Close_Date__c;
            opp.Name = deal.Name;
            opp.StageName = deal.Stage__c;
            opp.Description = deal.Description_L__c;
            opp.NextStep = deal.X7_Clear_Next_Step__c;
            opp.Campaignid = deal.Primary_Campaign_Source__c;
            opp.Probability = deal.Probability__c;
            opp.Type = deal.Company__c;

            newOpps.add(opp);
        }
        insert newOpps;
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

            opp.Accountid = dl.Account__c;
            opp.Amount = dl.Stair_Total__c;
            opp.CloseDate = dl.Close_Date__c;
            opp.Name = dl.Name;
            opp.StageName = dl.Stage__c;
            opp.Description = dl.Description_L__c;
            opp.NextStep = dl.X7_Clear_Next_Step__c;
            opp.Campaignid = dl.Primary_Campaign_Source__c;
            opp.Probability = dl.Probability__c;
            opp.Type = dl.Company__c;


        if(opp.Id != null){
            Opportunity Op = [Select Id, CloseDate from Opportunity where Id =: opp.Id];
            system.debug('=======Opportunity======='+Op);

            Op.CloseDate = dl.Close_Date__c;

            Update Op;
            system.debug('======UPDATE Opportunity======='+Op);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition

```
  if(opp.Id != null)
```

will never execute because you are creating new opportunity earlier

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
```

You are not updating the opp object (which I think is your goal). You are trying the Op only which are lines the code will never hit.

I think you should first find the matching opportunity then update it.

Comment: Yes. correct but if i don't have any relationship between this two object then what i need to do ? please suggest.

Comment: Any data that needs to be in sync need relation ... In Salesforce you can have a lookup from one object to another if it is 1:1 relation ... You can't keep data in sync without knowing which record belong to the other

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a record in a "before update" trigger.

Using an "after update" trigger must solve the issue.